# What is "A" in AGeV?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, terminology, si-units, heavy-ion

AGeV means GeV per nucleon. But why A letter is used for such a short cut? Why not NGeV, for example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an artifact of a long established coding for nuclei

- $Z$ -- the "atomic number" is the number of protons in the nucleus(or occasionally the "proton number")
- $A$ -- the "mass number" the number of nucleons in the nucleus

There is also the not often used

- $N$ -- the "neutron number"

The per-nucleon energy of course applies to both the protons and the neutrons, so you want $A$.

---

And yeah, the use of these letters doesn't make much sense, but it has been that way for a long, long time.

Comment: And I was wondering what Ampere-GeV should be...

Answer (score 9):

The $A$ is a variable; it's actually $A\text{ GeV}$, where $A$ is the mass number.

For example, RHIC has run Au-Au collisions at a beam energy of $100A\text{ GeV}$ (among other values). You would interpret this as $100A$ being the number of GeV. With gold nuclei, $A = 197$, and so that is $(100\times 197)\text{ GeV} = 19700\text{ GeV}$ total energy per nucleus.

Answer (score 2):

N.GeV would be confusing as the symbol N is commonly used to denote the number of neutrons.

From the Wikipedia article on [Atomic Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_number):

> The atomic number, Z, should not be confused with the mass number, A,
>   which is the number of nucleons, the total number of protons and
>   neutrons in the nucleus of an atom. The number of neutrons, N, is
>   known as the neutron number of the atom; thus, A = Z + N.