# How to convert GeV to AGeV?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, terminology, si-units, heavy-ion

The beam energy is sometimes in AGeV in collider papers. I'm stuck on how to convert AGeV to GeV.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34522/2451

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "A" in AGeV?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34522/)